# Dropdown list - default value

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a dropdown list of all available printers:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    For Each l_pr In Application.Printers

      Me.dropdown.RowSourceType = "Value List"
      Me.dropdown.AddItem l_pr.DeviceName
   Next

   Me.dropdown.DefaultValue = Application.Printer.DeviceName

End Sub
```

I'd like to have the default printer to be selected when the form is loaded. I thought you could do that with DefaultValue (see my code), but nothing is displayed this way.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make your printer selection by assigning to the dropdown's `Value` property instead of `DefaultValue`.

I verified this code with a new form in Access 2007 ...

```vb
Private Sub Form_Load()
    Dim l_pr As Printer
    Me.dropdown.RowSourceType = "Value List"
    For Each l_pr In Application.Printers
        Me.dropdown.AddItem l_pr.DeviceName
    Next
    'Me.dropdown.DefaultValue = Application.Printer.DeviceName
    Me.dropdown.Value = Application.Printer.DeviceName
    Set l_pr = Nothing
End Sub
```

I moved the `RowSourceType` statement before the `For` loop ... you only need to run that statement once.

Also notice `Dim l_pr As Printer` ... declaring variables is recommended practice in VBA.  Include `Option Explicit` in the Declarations section of your form module and then run *Debug->Compile* from the VB Editor's main menu.  Fix anything else the compiler complains about before troubleshooting other code problems.